# Javascript - Group by one property, sort by another

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, and I currently have them sorted by one property (a number). I have a sort button that will allow a user to sort them by another attribute (a string). How can I sort them by a *specific* value, and keep them in the order of the number sort in javascript?

A quick example, using a person with a name, age, and favorite color:

```
Steve, 27, Blue
Joe, 28, Red
John, 30, Green
Jane, 33, Blue
Julie, 35, Blue
Kevin, 40, Red
```

So, if a user wanted to sort the list by people with the favorite color of Red, I'd want it to show like this:

```
Joe, 28, Red
Kevin, 40, Red
Steve, 27, Blue
Jane, 33, Blue
Julie, 35, Blue
John, 30, Green
```

The order of the property *after* the selected one doesn't matter, as long as they are grouped and sorted by age. For example, the above list (sorted by **red**) could have John listed after Kevin, so long as all Steve, Jane and Julie all stayed in the same order.

Basically, I want to **group by** a string, and then **sort the group** by a number.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: In case anyone wants to make something, here's the JSON: http://pastebin.com/hVmQRLvM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to `ORDER BY (color = Red), color, age` (not SQL syntax): first Red, then grouped by color, then age per group.

That's tricky in 1 sorter...

I think this is the one:

```
function(a, b) {
    if (a.color == 'Red') {
        if (b.color == 'Red') {
            // Both Red, so check Age
            return a.age - b.age;
        }
        // A is Red, so to top
        return -1;
    }

    if (b.color == 'Red') {
        // B is red, so to top
        return 1;
    }

    if (a.color == b.color) {
        // Same color, so check Age
        return a.age - b.age;
    }

    // Different color, so check that
    return a.color < b.color ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Result seems like it:

```
Joe     28  Red
Kevin   40  Red
Steve   27  Blue
Jane    33  Blue
Julie   35  Blue
John    30  Green
```

Maybe it could've been shorter, but I can't think anymore.

Demo on http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/83sm2squ/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function takes a function as a parameter that can be used to do arbitrary sorts.

An example that would accomplish your desired sort:

```
people.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.color == 'Red' && b.color != 'Red') return 1;
    if (a.color != 'Red' && b.color == 'Red') return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Technically you'd only have to check `a.color`. `b` is irrelevant if you only care about "Red". `return a.color == 'Red' ? -1 : 1;`